# Primefaces header click toggle

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have two panels in panel header to click i want toggle panel.

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".ui-panel:has(.ui-panel-titlebar-icon) .ui-panel-titlebar", function(e) {
    console.log("click:");
PF("widgetVar").toggle();//Need to know how given widgetVar

});
</script>

<p:panel id="userPanel1" widgetVar="org1"  toggleable="true" collapsed="true">
.....
</p:panel>

<p:panel id="userPanel2" widgetVar="org2"  toggleable="true" collapsed="true">
.....
</p:panel>
```

my doubt panel header to click send widgetVar and Toggle  current panel.That is PF("widgetVar").toggle() to set pass current panel widgetVar on header click event and In same to I use PF("widgetVar").collapse() panel.

Comment: Can you try to translate it better ? I'm not sure what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In [the primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panel.xhtml) there are examples:

```
    <p:panel id="toggleable" header="Toggleable" toggleable="true" closable="true" toggleSpeed="500" closeSpeed="500" widgetVar="panel" style="margin-bottom:20px">
        <f:facet name="options">
            <p:menu>
                <p:submenu label="Settings">
                    <p:menuitem value="Toggle" url="#" icon="ui-icon-newwin" onclick="PF('panel').toggle();" />
                </p:submenu>
            </p:menu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panel>
```

Just change:

`PF('panel').toggle();` to `PF('panel').toggle();PF('panel').collapse();` and remove that script (unless you want to log a click lol). You can add as many function as you like in the `onclick` attribute and you can even do this like this: `onclick="alert('hi');"`. That is useful for debugging sometimes.

If that wasn't what you were asking for please edit your post. If it was you can accept my answer by clicking the v under the score to show your gratitude and to give me free karma!

Cheers.

Comment: My doubt is ui-titlebar click to toggle panel and  also p:panel ajax event=click is not supported so i use above script

Comment: @user5092860 Isn't that an accordion then ? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml